# Using ajax with sonata admin list view pagination

Tags: sonata-admin

I'm using sonata admin in my project. In the list view sonata refresh the page when I clik to get the second list from pagination. That's the default behavior of sonata.Is there any way to use ajax call with list view pagination !!!

[image]

Same question when using sortable list view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, but you have to overwrite some of the basic functionality of the sonata admin bundle.

Tested with

- symfony 2.6.6
- sonata admin-bundle dev-master (4f23e1a30e49681bf8ebdbbae549848784be7699)

**1. Edit your bundles services.yml**

You have to implement your own CrudController and a new list template. Tell this in services.yml

```
sonata.admin.youradmin:
        class: Your\Bundle\Admin\YourAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "groupname", label: "grouplabel" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Your\Bundle\Entity\EntityClass
            - YourBundle:YourNewCrud # <- add your crud class here
        calls:
            - [ setLabelTranslatorStrategy, ["@sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore"]]
            - [ setTemplate, [list, YourBundle:YourAdmin:list.html.twig]] # <- tell sonata you want this template for list
```

**2. Add new twig template**

Now add the following template to your bundles Resources/views/YourAdmin/list.html.twig:

```
{# extends from the normal base_list.html.twig, but when this template is
   rendered via an ajax-call, extend from an ajax-list.html.twig, we'll
   add later #}
{% extends app.request.xmlHttpRequest
? 'YourBundle:ajax-list.html.twig'
: 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list.html.twig' %}

{# YourBundle:ajax-list.html.twig is the path where you have your template, if your template is inside views/Admin, then put it like this: YourBundle:Admin:ajax-list.html.twig #}

{# Here I copied the list_table block from the original list.html.twig 
   from sonata.. I added custom JS-code below to do the ajax call #}
{% block list_table %}
    {# The code in this block is copied from sonata.. I just added the JS-code below, and added the 'actionList' id here #}

    <div id="actionList" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        {% if admin.hasRoute('batch') %}
        <form action="{{ admin.generateUrl('batch', {'filter': admin.filterParameters}) }}" method="POST" >
            <input type="hidden" name="_sonata_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
            {% endif %}

            {# Add a margin if no pager to prevent dropdown cropping on window #}
            <div class="box box-primary" {% if admin.datagrid.pager.lastPage == 1 %}style="margin-bottom: 100px;"{% endif %}>
                <div class="box-body {% if admin.datagrid.results|length > 0 %}table-responsive no-padding{% endif %}">
                    {{ sonata_block_render_event('sonata.admin.list.table.top', { 'admin': admin }) }}

                    {% block list_header %}{% endblock %}

                    {% set batchactions = admin.batchactions %}
                    {% if admin.datagrid.results|length > 0 %}
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped sonata-ba-list">
                            {% block table_header %}
                                <thead>
                                <tr class="sonata-ba-list-field-header">
                                    {% for field_description in admin.list.elements %}
                                        {% if admin.hasRoute('batch') and field_description.getOption('code') == '_batch' and batchactions|length > 0 %}
                                            <th class="sonata-ba-list-field-header sonata-ba-list-field-header-batch">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="list_batch_checkbox">
                                            </th>
                                        {% elseif field_description.getOption('code') == '_select' %}
                                            <th class="sonata-ba-list-field-header sonata-ba-list-field-header-select"></th>
                                        {% elseif field_description.name == '_action' and app.request.isXmlHttpRequest %}
                                            {# Action buttons disabled in ajax view! #}
                                        {% elseif field_description.getOption('ajax_hidden') == true and app.request.isXmlHttpRequest %}
                                            {# Disable fields with 'ajax_hidden' option set to true #}
                                        {% else %}
                                            {% set sortable = false %}
                                            {% if field_description.options.sortable is defined and field_description.options.sortable %}
                                                {% set sortable             = true %}
                                                {% set sort_parameters      = admin.modelmanager.sortparameters(field_description, admin.datagrid) %}
                                                {% set current              = admin.datagrid.values._sort_by == field_description or admin.datagrid.values._sort_by.fieldName == sort_parameters.filter._sort_by %}
                                                {% set sort_active_class    = current ? 'sonata-ba-list-field-order-active' : '' %}
                                                {% set sort_by              = current ? admin.datagrid.values._sort_order : field_description.options._sort_order %}
                                            {% endif %}

                                            {% spaceless %}
                                                <th class="sonata-ba-list-field-header-{{ field_description.type}} {% if sortable %} sonata-ba-list-field-header-order-{{ sort_by|lower }} {{ sort_active_class }}{% endif %}">
                                                    {% if sortable %}<a href="{{ admin.generateUrl('list', sort_parameters) }}">{% endif %}
                                                        {{ admin.trans(field_description.label, {}, field_description.translationDomain) }}
                                                        {% if sortable %}</a>{% endif %}
                                                </th>
                                            {% endspaceless %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                            {% endblock %}

                            {% block table_body %}
                                <tbody>
                                {% include admin.getTemplate('outer_list_rows_' ~ admin.getListMode()) %}
                                </tbody>
                            {% endblock %}

                            {% block table_footer %}
                            {% endblock %}
                        </table>
                    {% else %}
                        <div class="info-box">
                            <span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                            <div class="info-box-content">
                                <span class="info-box-text">{{ 'no_result'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</span>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%"></div>
                                </div>
                            <span class="progress-description">
                                {% if not app.request.xmlHttpRequest %}
                                    {% include 'SonataAdminBundle:Button:create_button.html.twig' %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </span>
                            </div><!-- /.info-box-content -->
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}

                    {{ sonata_block_render_event('sonata.admin.list.table.bottom', { 'admin': admin }) }}
                </div>
                {% block list_footer %}
                    {% if admin.datagrid.results|length > 0 %}
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <div class="form-inline clearfix">
                                {% if not app.request.isXmlHttpRequest %}
                                    <div class="pull-left">
                                        {% if admin.hasRoute('batch') and batchactions|length > 0  %}
                                            {% block batch %}
                                                <script>
                                                    {% block batch_javascript %}
                                                    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                                                        $('#list_batch_checkbox').on('ifChanged', function () {
                                                            $(this)
                                                                    .closest('table')
                                                                    .find('td.sonata-ba-list-field-batch input[type="checkbox"], div.sonata-ba-list-field-batch input[type="checkbox"]')
                                                                    .iCheck($(this).is(':checked') ? 'check' : 'uncheck')
                                                            ;
                                                        });

                                                        $('td.sonata-ba-list-field-batch input[type="checkbox"], div.sonata-ba-list-field-batch input[type="checkbox"]')
                                                                .on('ifChanged', function () {
                                                                    $(this)
                                                                            .closest('tr, div.sonata-ba-list-field-batch')
                                                                            .toggleClass('sonata-ba-list-row-selected', $(this).is(':checked'))
                                                                    ;
                                                                })
                                                                .trigger('ifChanged')
                                                        ;
                                                    });
                                                    {% endblock %}
                                                </script>

                                                {% block batch_actions %}
                                                    <label class="checkbox" for="{{ admin.uniqid }}_all_elements">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="all_elements" id="{{ admin.uniqid }}_all_elements">
                                                        {{ 'all_elements'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
                                                        ({{ admin.datagrid.pager.nbresults }})
                                                    </label>

                                                    <select name="action" style="width: auto; height: auto" class="form-control">
                                                        {% for action, options in batchactions %}
                                                            <option value="{{ action }}">{{ options.label }}</option>
                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                    </select>
                                                {% endblock %}

                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" value="{{ 'btn_batch'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}">
                                            {% endblock %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        {% if admin.hasRoute('export') and admin.isGranted("EXPORT") and admin.getExportFormats()|length %}
                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></i>
                                                    {{ "label_export_download"|trans({}, "SonataAdminBundle") }}
                                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                                </button>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    {% for format in admin.getExportFormats() %}
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="{{ admin.generateUrl('export', admin.modelmanager.paginationparameters(admin.datagrid, 0) + {'format' : format}) }}">
                                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i>
                                                            {{ format|upper }}
                                                        </a>
                                                    <li>
                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>

                                            &nbsp;-&nbsp;
                                        {% endif %}

                                        {% block pager_results %}
                                            {% include admin.getTemplate('pager_results') %}
                                        {% endblock %}
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>

                            {% block pager_links %}
                                {% if admin.datagrid.pager.haveToPaginate() %}
                                    <hr/>
                                    {% include admin.getTemplate('pager_links') %}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endblock %}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            {% if admin.hasRoute('batch') %}
        </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

 {# When this request is not via ajax, add the following JS-code
    this will trigger an ajax-request, and uses the normal a-href location #}
 {% if not app.request.xmlHttpRequest %}
        <script>
            $('body').on('click', '.pagination li a', function(e){
                var url = $(this).attr('href');

                $.post(url,
                    {},
                    function(response){
                        if(response.code == 100 && response.success){
                            $('#actionList').replaceWith(response.content);
                        }
                    }
                );

                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });

        </script>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**3. Add ajax template**
We do this to prevent the original bundle to output everything we don't need:

YourBundle/Resources/views/YourAdmin/ajax-list.html.twig:

```
{% block list_table %}{% endblock %}
```

**4. Add custom CrudController**
Now the only thing left to do is, that we want to overwrite the original listAction so that we can return JSON in stead of pure HTML. Add YourCrudController.php in YourBundle/Controller/

Add the following

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;    
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class YourCrudController extends Controller
{       

    public function listAction(Request $request = null)
    {    
        // call original listAction function to get the right HTML
        $response = parent::listAction($request);

        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            // disable the profile, to prevent profiler code
            $this->container->get('profiler')->disable();

            // return JsonResponse
            return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true, 'code' => 100, 'content' => $response->getContent()));
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Sit back, hit f5, click the pager and enjoy!